# Does jQuery support html escaping of data retrieved from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most `MVC` frameworks support escaping of server data, before putting them on the web page. I couldn't find any option in `jQuery`'s `ajax` method to do the same. In fact, I couldn't even find a native jQuery function to escape strings for proper display on the page (Putting the contents in a `div`, and calling `.html(`) on it, is not guaranteed to preserve white space). Why is it that this function is not available in jQuery, but you can find it in `underscore` and `prototype` libraries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you want to prevent HTML markup (e.g. `<br/>`, `<a>`, `&`) from being treated as HTML markup: you just want to display it straight to the user. This helps to prevent attacks like XSS (cross-site scripting).

This is actually very easy with jQuery, but it isn't the same as escaping. It's just using the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method, which means the content is treated as textual content, not as markup.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#yourElement').text(data);
    }
});
```

It is different working client-side to server-side. Working server-side, you are dealing with markup, which needs to be escaped to stop the parser treating content that should be text as markup. On the client-side, the markup is already parsed, so all you need is to tell the browser "this is text content". This can be done in a variety of ways (`innerText`, `document.createTextNode`, or even `document.createCDATASection`); jQuery's `data` method does this for you.